# ReactJS - fetch function: Why am I getting uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, reactjs

GET request works successfully, and I am now trying to make a POST to a url with the following:

```
var data = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'number': 'TEST12345'
}

var post = {
    "number": "TEST12345",
    "parameters":
    {
        "START_NUMBER" : {
          "value": 5,
          "effectiveDate": "2016/01/01 10:10"
        }
    }
}

var myInit = {
  method: 'POST',
  mode: 'cors',
  headers: data,
  body: JSON.stringify(post)
};

fetch('http://localhost:8080/form/upload/post/save', myInit)
.then(result=>{console.log(result.json())})
```

but I got the following log:

[image]

All seems correct but why the error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body methods returns a promise

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/form/upload/post/save', myInit)
  .then(result => result.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text

Comment: Tried it but does not log anything and only gives me the same error: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

Comment: @JoKo Add a catch as well, .catch(err => console.log(err)), but I imagine it will only tell you what you already know

Comment: @aw04 Yup, gave me: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. What  could be the issue? Everything seems right...

Comment: What is returned by your save call ?

Comment: @DimitriMockelyn Sorry but could you clarify what save call is?

Comment: I meant your post call. What is returned by the webservice ?

Comment: @JoKo your api response probably doesnt return json. try `result => result.text()`

Comment: @Daniel_L Thank you it works! Now I am trying to do an authentication header, where when a user registers it will send over the username and password. How should I go about doing so?